# Please migrate/merge #888497 onto Unix & Linux SE

Tags: discussion, migration

[snap-confine refuses to launch application to avoid permission attack](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888497) is a non-Ubuntu question about snap configuration (or maybe a snap bug). Please:

- migrate to https://unix.stackexchange.com, or
- merge with https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379421 (same error message but framed around a kernel issue)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm afraid we can do neither. Questions older than 60 days [cannot be migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/203101) and we can't merge without migrating.

> Only questions which are less than 60 days old can be migrated; this rule also applies to moderators.<sup>1</sup>
>
> <sup>1</sup> <sub>After 60 days, migrations can only be performed by Stack Exchange employees. These are performed only in very, very rare procedural cases and are usually not done on request.</sub>